# При инициализации проекта npm init в VSCode ошибка

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
https://json.schemastore.org/package": Не удалось загрузить схему из "https://json.schemastore.org/package": Service Unavailable. The server is currently unavailable (overloaded or down).
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Service Unavailable</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=u.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это внутренняя проблема одного из установленных в vscode плагинов, возможно "JSON Editor plugin". вряд ли это может помешать вам разрабатывать.

Comment: Да спасибо, но я не нашел в чем причина.)

Comment: плагин лезет за схемой данных на сервис xyz, сервис xyz временно сдох. что сложного?